# Prove that combinatoric sum approaches $-\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, combinations

This question arose from a small part of a larger problem that I've been working on recently.

How can I show that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k} {n \choose k} = -\infty$$

Computationally, this appears to be the case: successive partial sums decrease without bound (albeit rather slowly) with increasing $n$.
However, I've had trouble finding a closed form for the sum or showing the result analytically.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: WolframAlpha says your Limit is $-1$

Comment: Representing the sum by the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^n -1}{x}\,dx$$ is one possible approach. This tells that your integral diverges to $-\infty$ at logarithmic speed.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Wolframalpha "is wrong".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}k{n\choose k}
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}x^{k-1}\,dx
=\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^n-1}{x}\,dx\\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\,dy
=-\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n y^{k-1}\,dy
=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) of the sequence of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The first claim has already been shown by Lord Shark, and the fact that $H_n\approx \log(n)$ follows from

$$ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = O(1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{2k}}{1-\frac{1}{2k}}\right)\stackrel{\text{Telescopic!}}{=}O(1)+\log(2n+1). $$